# how many terms are missing in the indeterminate partial sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I know in this particular indeterminate partial sum S = $3^n - 3^{n+1} + 3^{n+2} - 3^{n+3} + \cdots + 3^{3n}$ where $a=3^n$ and $r=-3$. I know if $3^1$ were the first term, there would be $3n$ terms but its not the first term $3^n$ is. So I am missing $3^1,3^2,3^3, \cdots , 3^{n-1}$ = $\,$ $n-1$ terms that are missing to the left of $3^n$. $\,$ Therefore, there are $3n-(n-1) = 2n+1$ terms.

How many terms does S = $3^k + 3^{k-1} + 3^{k-2} + \cdots + 3^{-2k}$ have? In the above I knew that $3^{n-1}$ terms are to the left of $3^n$ because we're adding 1 to the exponent each time. However, here we are subtracting 1 from the exponent each time so what's to the left of $3^k$? How many terms are there missing to the left of $3^k$ I must see the leftward expansion of the missing terms and so therefore there are how many terms are there? Need to follow the same process i did for the example involving n.

Answer (score 1):

You are just counting down from $k$ to $-2k$ by $1$'s.  There are $k-(-2k)+1=3k+1$ terms.  The $+1$ comes because you count both ends of the interval, like when counting from $5$ to $10$ there are $10-5+1=6$ terms.  Try it!

Comment: thanks. But if you look i was MAINLY concerning to the left of $3^k$. I was able to figure out $3^1 \cdots 3^{n-1}$ comes to the left of $3^n$ counting up. So what's to the left of $3^k$ counting down??

Comment: I don't think there is a reasonable answer to that.  There is nothing before $3^k$ because that is where you start.  If you count away from $0$ it can be useful to imagine the "missing" terms there and count them all, then subtract the missing ones.  The similar thing here would be to count the $k$ before $0, 0$ and the $2k$ after $0$.

Comment: Finally, thank u!!